# How to enforce module hierarchy/dependency

Tags: .net, design-patterns, module

The Validation module is divided into #1, #2 and General as below

```
======================================================================
---------------------------     ---------------------------
| #1 Validation Sub Module|     | #2 Validation Sub Module|
---------------------------     ---------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------
|                    General Validation Module             |
------------------------------------------------------------
======================================================================
```

To validate something, one has to go through sub modules but not directly call General module.

How to enforce (other than code review, preferably in .NET) no piece of code should call General module directly? Reflection !!!

**EDIT**
I am also seeking some solutions provided by Software Engineering principles i.e. beyond anything specific to a language/platform so are there any design patterns or software design guidelines or development practices?

Comment: Make the General Validation Module abstract class

Answer (score 1):

Make all types in general validation module internal. If each validation module is a separate assembly you will have to use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the general validation module assembly to allow each validation sub module assembly access to the internal members. If you can put all validation modules into a single assembly you do not have to do this.

Comment: Hmm, while using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` would require add the name of the new assembly each time, nevertheless it is valuable.